# Getting group section in jasper reports API java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How can I get the group header section in my java program using jasper reports api.
I have to get an element from the group header section using its key, but i am unable to get the group header section using jasper reports API.
Any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JasperReport report = ...;
report.getGroups();
// identify group by name
JRGroup group = ...;
group.getGroupHeaderSection();
```